# como decodificar este texto en JavaScript (Hola, u00bfen quu00e9 puedo ayudarte?)

Tags: javascript

Esta codificado pero quiero sustituir las letras donde corresponde las tildes y el signo de interrogacion, que funcion podria utilizar para hacer esto?

Comment: ¿podrías poner el ejemplo en el cuerpo de la pregunta, no en el título? Probablemente tenga `"\"` que no se están viendo... La idea es que tu pregunta tenga un **[mcve]** (por favor lee esa página de la ayuda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cadena `Hola, u00bfen quu00e9 puedo ayudarte?` usa codificación Unicode pero está incompleta.

En lugar de

- `u00bf` debe ser  `\u00bf`
- `u00e9` deber ser `\u00e9`

El siguiente código escribe la frase decodificada

```js
document.write('Hola, \u00bfen qu\u00e9 puedo ayudarte?')
```

Referencia

- [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String)